# Jira API - how to ADD a custom field to an existing issue

Tags: migration, jira, jira-rest-api

Given a project and some issues in it, I want to create a new custom field and populate it for some issues.

I see that the `editmeta` api returns the list of fields that are already on the issue and can be edited (updated). But how do I edit the metadata itself?

(Motivation: we migrate from another tool and want to preserve some original data after the standard export/import is done)

Comment: Are you running on Jira Server (on-premise) or Jira Cloud?

Comment: Also note, that Jira has prepared several importer to import data from various existing systems (without having to script import over REST API). Just check https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/migrating-from-other-issue-trackers-938847532.html if the list on the right side can be of any use.

Comment: @CraZ I haven't been on the project from the beginning, I assume that the built-in import capabilities were exhausted. I was asked to write a custom script to add the data that was left out. But I'll look at your link, thanks.

Comment: @CraZ it's Cloud

Comment: @CraZ BTW our tool (Wrike) is not even on the list...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add new custom field(s) Jira administration. You cannot add new fields on-the-fly using common "edit issue" method.

If you are admin of whole Jira system, you can add it by yourself. If not, you will need to ask your Jira admin to do it. The new field must be also added to proper issue screens so that the field is available for editing (either from UI or from REST API).

See more here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/create-a-custom-field-991923727.html

Comment: thanks. My question is about adding such field (that was created AFTER the issue)  to an issue. May be my terminology isn't correct? Can an issue edit any field, even those it wasn't initially created with, provided it's added to a screen?

Comment: Not sure if I understand this comment. If you want to edit additional field after the import, you can just edit the issue. The new field must a) be created in Jira & b) available on (Edit) screen. Then the field would appear on editmeta and you could edit/update/add the values for that field.